# How to force insert document to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, go

when I am inserting a document to MongoDB collection I get an error: **E11000 duplicate key error collection**
I would like to override the existing document with a new one.
Is there any way to force insert new data with the same _id field?
I am using go

Comment: There is two options , 1st you can update the document without affecting  the _id, 2nd you can remove the document with the _id and insert new document with the same _id. Maybe check the option to update with { upsert: true } , that way you will insert to new _id if the _id do not exist yet, but update if document exist...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot insert two separate documents in MongoDB with the same `_id` field. This is stated in the documentation on [document structure](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#field-names):

> The field name _id is reserved for use as a primary key; its value must be unique in the collection, is immutable, and may be of any type other than an array.

What you're describing sounds more like an upsert, an operation that updates a document if it exists, and if it does not, inserts it instead. You could accomplish this by using [updateOne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/) and setting the `upsert` flag to `true`.